# How to enable "Download a Copy" button

Tags: sharepoint-server

[image: Download a Copy button disabled]

Hi all,

When i try to download multiple files from our Sharepoint Server, the "download a copy" button gets disabled, even for admin login.. Any suggestions, how to enable it?

Thanks..

Comment: You cannot use "Download a Copy" when multiple items are selected, please select a single document and try..

Comment: Hi Arsalan, you mean this feature is not present for multiple files at all in sharepoint? and also, same problem when i select a folder, download a copy button gets disbaled.. any suggestions.. thanks

Comment: Yes this is not for multiple files/folders.. If you need to copy multiple items, try opening the document library in explorer instead..